# Get calc-value from CSS with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I want a div to have at min-height = width. This can ofcourse be done with css, but I have other stuff going on that prevents the `height = 0`, `padding = 100%` trick), so I'm using jQuery
I have trouble fetching a calc-css value, it just comes out as `0px`, and I wonder if there is a work around this?

css

```
.box{
width: calc(50% - 10px);
height: auto;
}
```

jQuery

```
var box = $('.box');
var box_w = box.width();

box.css('min-height', box_w);
```

Comment: It's just a class for my div

Comment: Haha, sry, that was a class from my original code, I wanted to use .box to not confuse you, and managed to do just that!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be here:

```
var box = $('.box');
var box_w = lbInfo.width(); // <----you need to change 'lbInfo' to 'box'
```

i guess you want to change it like:

```
var box = $('.box');
var box_w = box.css('width'); // because you have set the width property in css

lbInfo.css('min-height', box_w);
```

Comment: I still get "min-height: 0px"

Comment: Ok, I get it working now in jsFiddle, but not in my wordpress-site, which is weird.

Comment: Could be because in your site you have more than one element with that class

Comment: Yes, I do. But all has the same width. Where's the interference?

Comment: My problem was related to a parent div with overflow: hidden, so never mind. Sorry for the fuzz!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
$(".box").css("min-height", function() { 
    return $(this).width(); // or outerWidth() or $(this).css('width');
});
```

This way if you have multiple `.box` they will all have their `min-height`s set to their corresponding `width`s